# Using Gradle to find dependency tree

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to use Gradle to produce a tree of what depends on what?

I have a project and would like to find out all the dependencies so I may be able to prune it a little with forward declarations etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is gradle artifact dependency graph command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288133/what-is-gradle-artifact-dependency-graph-command)

Answer (score 956):

Without modules:

```
gradle dependencies
```

For Android:

```
 gradle app:dependencies
```

Using gradle wrapper:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

**Note:** Replace `app` with the project module name.

Additionally, if you want to check if something is `compile` vs. `testCompile` vs `androidTestCompile` dependency as well as what is pulling it in:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration testCompile --dependency <name>
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration androidTestCompile --dependency <name>
```

Comment: ah, 'app' is a submodule of your current gradle project I guess. Turns out I didn't read this in your answer: "where app is your project module." Thanks for the reply!

Comment: see also how to achieve that with android studio help https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree

Comment: @ChadBingham : i try your suggestion but it's didn't work :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646103/why-gradlew-appdependencyinsight-failed

Comment: I also didn't know the project module (this legacy project has a really weird structure). But this command helped me `./gradlew -q dependencies :dependencies` It looks on all your folders :P

Comment: In fact `./gradlew :dependencies` will work. It will list the dependencies for all your projects, but it is easy to find the right one.

Comment: @Jenix it depends on the version of your ./gradlew and gradle are running.If ./gradlew has a higher version it can probably have more tasks.

Comment: On an non-Android project with Gradle wrapper `./gradlew dependencies`  works (while `./gradlew app:dependencies` gives me the following failure / exception "Project 'app' not found in root project 'spring-petclinic'."

Comment: This does not show the dependency tree (transitive dependencies). It just lists out the direct implementations.

Comment: It's not clear how to read this report, what does \--- mean (compared to +---)?

Comment: WRT Windows Android Studio, requires JAVA_HOME env var which can be Android Studio's C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr

Comment: @Marit It's because `app` must be replaced with the **your** project _module name_ (unless you indeed have a module named 'app').

Answer (score 285):

You can render the dependency tree with the command `gradle dependencies`. For more information check the section [Listing dependencies in a project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies) in the online user guide.

Comment: When I do this with my Android project, all I get is this output:  http://pastebin.com/fHFigAuY Suggestions?

Comment: @Nilzor You are probably executing the command in the wrong directory (that doesn't contain the `build.gradle` file) or your build file doesn't apply any plugin.

Comment: you can get dependencies for a specific project using gradle :project:dependencies

Comment: [Android Studio Plugin - Gradle View](https://github.com/rholder/gradle-view) to analyse dependencies.

Comment: If you use the wrapper: `./gradlew dependencies`

Answer (score 219):

If you find it hard to navigate console output of `gradle dependencies`, you can add the [Project reports plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#project_reports_plugin):

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

For a multimodule project (most of projects), you need to configure the report to include the subprojects, too:

```
htmlDependencyReport {
    projects = project.allprojects
}
```

And generate a HTML report using:

```
$ ./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

Report can normally be found in `build/reports/project/dependencies/index.html`

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: For me it was just `gradle htmlDependencyReport`

Comment: This doesn't work for multimodule projects. I just see and empty list.

Comment: Great find. Plugin actually does way more https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html

Comment: would be nice if it list are expanded by default to do a quick search. otherwise can go view html on chrome console and search..

Comment: @lorraine it can create plaintext report, `gradle dependencyReport`

Comment: This is what helped me

Comment: where to add htmlDependencyReport{ projects = project.allprojects } ?

Answer (score 91):

In Android Studio (at least since v2.3.3) you can run the command directly from the UI:

Click on the *Gradle* tab and then double click on *:yourmodule -> Tasks -> android -> androidDependencies*

The tree will be displayed in the *Gradle Console* tab

[image: An image is worth a thousand words]

Comment: how do i get the "gradle projects" view?

Comment: @user3526 click on the "gradle" tag found on the right side of your screen. Look at the attached image for reference

Comment: I found that this creates a flat list in AS 3.2.0, instead of a tree.  The command line variant creates a tree however.

Comment: @Tom run 'depencies' task under 'help' category not 'android'. It shows as tree

Answer (score 62):

Often the complete `testImplementation`, `implementation`, and `androidTestImplementation` dependency graph is too much to examine together. If you merely want the `implementation` dependency graph you can use:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies --configuration implementation
```

Source: [Listing dependencies in a project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)

Note: `compile` has been deprecated in more recent versions of Gradle and in more recent versions you are advised to shift all of your `compile` dependencies to `implementation`. Please see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413952/gradle-implementation-vs-api-configuration/44419574#44419574)

Comment: just a note: compile has been deprecated, people should now move to implementation

Comment: You can also use `:dependencies` instead of `app:dependencies`.

Answer (score 34):

For me, it was simply one command

in `build.gradle` add `plugin`

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

and then go to cmd and run following command

```
./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

This gives me an HTML report WOW Html report

---

> Or if you want the report in a `text file`, to make search easy use following command

```
gradlew dependencyReport
```

[image]

That's all my lord.

Comment: Great answer! Just in case, it is not obvious to someone the generated `html` file will be found in `build/reports/project/dependencies/root.html`

Comment: Produces an empty tree for a multi-module project.

Comment: @PavelVlasov `gradlew dependencyReport` this works as charm and give you full dependency tree

Comment: Isn't this solution with _project-report_ [already answered by devstr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41784667/5730279) ?!

Answer (score 33):

If you want to visualize your dependencies in a graph you can use [gradle-dependency-graph-generator](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-dependency-graph-generator-plugin) plugin.

Generally the output of this plugin can be found in **build/reports/dependency-graph** directory and it contains three files (.dot|.png|.svg) if you are using the **0.5.0** version of the plugin.

Example of dependences graph in a real app ([Chess Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vanniktech.chessclock)):

[image: graph]

Comment: Hey David, I did as was told in the plugin instructions. I applied plugin in project gradle but I am not seeing any reports folder in build directory. Is there anything we need to do other than build and run the project?

Comment: This plugin not show dependency version and conflicts. like this for Maven; https://github.com/janssk1/maven-graph-plugin/wiki/Manual This make it useless..

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateDependencyGraph'.
> Cannot invoke "com.kitfox.svg.SVGDiagram.setIgnoringClipHeuristic(boolean)" because "diagram" is null

Answer (score 25):

Things have moved forward in Gradle so I believe this question merits another answer.
Since Gradle 4.3, "**build scans**" were introduced. All relevant info is available in the Gradle docs ([1](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-build-scans/), [2](https://scans.gradle.com/)). For me, this seems to now be the easiest way to check your dependencies (and generally your build) in a clear, organized way.

They are very easy to create, just execute:

```
gradle build --scan
```

(or `./gradlew build --scan` if you use a wrapper)

This produces a randomly generated link where you can see your scan. When opening that link, you enter your email and gain full control of the link: eg. share it or delete it.  It has got *a lot of info about your build*, not just dependencies. You can see your dependencies, their hierarchies, the repository used to obtain them but also a lot of other stuff about your build, namely, its performance (which is of interest in big complex builds), your tests, even your console output and your system configuration, which JDK and JVM was used, max heap size etc.

This is a printscreen from a mock project:

[image: Build scan example]

> A build scan is a shareable record of a build that provides insights into what happened and why. You can create a build scan at scans.gradle.com for free.

Note however, that *info for your build process will be sent* to the Gradle servers. You have full control to delete it when you are finished with your inspection.

Finally, you can use build scans with Gradle versions earlier than 4.3 too, you just have to manually add the scans plugin in your buildscript.

**Edit**:
Incorporating some feedback from the comments some extra notes:
1) It is very difficult to do this by mistake or without understanding that some info for your build will be online (private to you, with the ability to delete it, but still online).

When executing `gradle build --scan` the following message appears:

```
Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle
Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you
accept these terms? [yes, no]
```

You have to explicitly write `yes` and then the message continues:

```
Publishing build scan...  
https://gradle.com/s/a12en0dasdu
```

2) In Gradle Enterprise you can host gradle build scans in your own servers. However I have no experience in this and my proposed approach was about the standard Gradle distribution, using Gradle's servers for your build scans.

3) Gradle itself promotes the build scans as the way to deal with most your build problems.

Comment: Sorry to downvote the answer, but IMO it's not answering the question and it's not warning clearly enough that by  `gradle build --scan` you publish details of your build somewhere on internet - and to delete it you have to associate it with working e-mail address.

Comment: Hey Michal, you are welcome to downvote if you feel that way. However I have to ask, did you try it? When executing  `gradle build --scan` in cmd, you are prompted: `Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]`. You have to manually write `yes`. Just after that, you get the message:  `Publishing build scan... https://gradle.com/s/a12en0dasdu` (randomly put link of the same type). So I believe it does warn you appropriately before. (1/2)

Comment: You can visit the link and delete the scan immediately, without an email or anything. As an answer, I believe it **does answer the question**. In fact, it shows you extra info about your dependencies (and going the extra mile: extra info for the whole build as well) in comparison to other approaches. If you don't find it to your liking that's totally okay, but it is (to my knowledge) the most comprehensive tool right now for the job, so it's valuable to have it in mind. Finally, it's promoted by Gradle itself, it is literally their [first guide](https://gradle.org/guides/) (2/2)

Comment: @Michal Sorry, forgot to tag you before so you may have not seen my comments. ( I also edited the post to incorporate the comments with which I answered to you. )

Comment: I haven't tried that - thanks for clarifying about the accepting of terms. I removed my -1.

Answer (score 25):

For Android, type this in terminal

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

It will list all the dependencies and the ones with newer versions for you to upgrade like

```
com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0 -> 27.1.1 (*)
```

Comment: No , I'm afraid the part about `(*)` is wrong.
`(*)` means this dependency declares to use the former(26.1.0) but actually build will use the latter version(27.1.1)
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34231202/9798666) talked about this.

Comment: @wkm exactly. The OP is wrong.

Answer (score 18):

For recent versions of Gradle (I tested with the 6.4.1 version):

```
gradle dependencies --configuration compileClasspath
```

or if you're using the Gradle Wrapper:

```
gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath
```

When building for Android with the 'debug' and 'release' compilation profiles, the `debugCompileClasspath` and `releaseCompileClasspath` configurations can be used instead of `compileClasspath`.

Answer (score 14):

I also found useful to run this:

```
./gradlew dI --dependency <your library>
```

This shows how are being dependencies resolved (`dependencyInsight`) and help you debugging into where do you need to force or exclude libraries in your `build.gradle`

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html

Comment: i try this like you say but it's didn't work :(  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646103/why-gradlew-appdependencyinsight-failed

Answer (score 11):

In Android Studio

1) Open terminal and ensure you are at project's root folder.

2) Run `./gradlew app:dependencies`  (if not using gradle wrapper, try  `gradle app:dependencies`)

Note that running `./gradle dependencies` will only give you dependency tree of project's root folder, so mentioning app in above manner, i.e.  `./gradlew app:dependencies` is important.

Comment: for me it worked without the "./" ,like that:
gradlew app:dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

Note that you may need to do something like `./gradlew <module_directory>:<module_name>:dependencies` if the module has extra directory before reach its build.gradle. When in doubt, do `./gradlew tasks --all` to check the name.

Answer (score 7):

Try either this

```
./gradlew dependencies > ~/dependencies.txt
```

or

```
gradle dependencies > ~/dependencies.txt`
```

which should write the dependencies in text file under user's home directory.

Answer (score 5):

If you want all the dependencies in a single file at the end within two steps.
Add this to your `build.gradle.kts` in the root of your project:

```
project.rootProject.allprojects {
    apply(plugin="project-report")

    this.task("allDependencies", DependencyReportTask::class) {
        evaluationDependsOnChildren()
        this.setRenderer(AsciiDependencyReportRenderer())
    }

}
```

Then apply:

```
./gradlew allDependencies | grep '\-\-\-' | grep -Po '\w+.*$' | awk -F ' ' '{ print $1 }' | sort | grep -v '\{' | grep -v '\[' | uniq | grep '.\+:.\+:.\+'
```

This will give you all the dependencies in your project and sub-projects along with all the 3rd party dependencies.

If you want to get this done in a programmatic way, then you'll need a custom renderer of the dependencies - you can start by extending the `AsciiDependencyReportRenderer` that prints an ascii graph of the dependencies by default.

Comment: This is interesting, as the first answer which touches on doing it programatically.
I've been struggling trying to programatically walk the tree using 
project.configurations.qdependency.allDependencies.each{}
but this doesn't loop over the 3rd party dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

double click and run dependency under help in gradle view

[image]