# Gradle won't exclude a module as requested

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I can't exclude a guava module in a build.gradle file using "exclude".

With this dependency block:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile(group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.19.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5') // !!! Doesn't work!!!
       ...
    }
...
}
```

I get the dependency tree below. Note that guava-jdk5 is not excluded.

```
+--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0
|    +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0
|    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0
|    |    |    ...
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    ...
|    \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0
```

...

Notice that the last line still includes the guava module, it has not been excluded.  Why? How to exclude it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle Transitive dependency exclusion is not working as expected. (How do I get rid of com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0 ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792398/gradle-transitive-dependency-exclusion-is-not-working-as-expected-how-do-i-get)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem was that another compile object was also dependent on the first level dependency that had the guava-jdk5 as a transitive dependency, so this other object was bringing in the unwanted module.

I was able to finally see this using

```
./gradlew -q :app:dependencyInsight --dependency guava --configuration compile
```

and could exclude it using

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Comment: how can we exclude particular class from package

Comment: @Ajay you can't do that in Gradle. You can only exclude transitive dependencies, not specific classes or packages from those dependencies or transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 23):

An answer by the question's author didn't help me, because it's too narrow / concrete.
This is a modified approach, which works for exclusion of any module:

1. Check currently recognized dependencies using this command in the "Terminal":

   ```
   gradlew app:dependencies
   ```

The command is issued from the root of your project and "app" here should be replaced with a name of your application's "module".

You may also cd inside your application's folder and launch this:

```
..\gradlew -q dependencies
```

Note: Use `../gradle` on Linux.

You will see that *several* configurations exist, not "compile" only (e.g. "_debugCompile" etc.). Each "configuration" has its own dependencies! This is why e.g. excluding something in "compile" configuration may be not enough.

2. Now apply exclusion to all "configurations" this way: 
   Add this block to your application's ("module") gradle.build file (with your list of modules to exclude, of course :-) ):

   ```
   configurations {
       all {
           exclude module: 'httpclient'
           exclude module: 'httpcore'
       }
   }
   ```

   Tip: Advances exclusion cases are discussed e.g. here: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-exclude-specific-transitive-dependencies-of-something-i-depend-on/17991/7
3. Repeat steps 1. and 2. until you don't see modules, which you want to exclude, in a list of dependencies of any configuration.

Tip: Here, inside "all" block, you may decide to put:

```
transitive = false
```

And you will get rid of all transitive dependencies.

Comment: Shouldn't you also use `group: 'com.some.group'`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky If module doesn't fully identify an artifact to exclude, you may use group also, e.g.:

exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'