# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.whitespace()

Tags: unit-testing, robolectric, android-guava

I'm writing android unit tests with Robolectric. When I run my tests currently, I keep getting the above error.

I have looked at and tried tons of suggested solutions from here, but none of them have resolved this error.

So far I have looked at the dependency tree and I can see two versions of guava being used:

```
+--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0@jar
+--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android@jar
```

After noticing this, I have then tried to:

1. exclude the first dependency

   ```
   buildscript {
     repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
    }
      dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
      classpath ('org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1') {
       exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
      }

     }
   }
   ```
2. upgrade the guava version to the latest

   ```
   api 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
   ```

This is what the error looks like:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher.whitespace()Lcom/google/common/base/CharMatcher;

at org.robolectric.res.StringResources.processStringResources(StringResources.java:19)
at org.robolectric.res.StaxValueLoader.onEnd(StaxValueLoader.java:33)
at org.robolectric.res.StaxDocumentLoader.doParse(StaxDocumentLoader.java:66)
at org.robolectric.res.StaxDocumentLoader.loadResourceXmlFile(StaxDocumentLoader.java:30)
at org.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.loadFile(DocumentLoader.java:48)
at org.robolectric.res.DocumentLoader.load(DocumentLoader.java:27)
at org.robolectric.res.ResourceTableFactory.parseResourceFiles(ResourceTableFactory.java:149)
at org.robolectric.res.ResourceTableFactory.lambda$newFrameworkResourceTable$0(ResourceTableFactory.java:26)
at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:50)
at org.robolectric.res.ResourceTableFactory.newFrameworkResourceTable(ResourceTableFactory.java:12)
at org.robolectric.internal.SdkEnvironment.getSystemResourceTable(SdkEnvironment.java:35)
at org.robolectric.ApkLoader.getSystemResourceTable(ApkLoader.java:32)
at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.injectResourceStuffForLegacy(ParallelUniverse.java:252)
at org.robolectric.android.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:126)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:379)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:252)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:130)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

And this is my Test class currently:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {

MyTestFragment myTestFragment;

 @Test
public void fragmentIsNotNull() throws Exception{
    myTestFragment = MyTestFragment.newInstance();
    assertNotNull(myTestFragment);
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally been able to get this to work by following the answer given here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25792398/gradle-transitive-dependency-exclusion-is-not-working-as-expected-how-do-i-get) from someone with a similar problem.

The issue was two conflicting guava dependencies as I pointed above.

```
+--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:13.0@jar
+--- com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android@jar
```

This is what I had tried before, to exclude guava,

```
configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
      }
```

But the guava-jdk-5 dependency was still being maintained.

So I finally added this to my gradle file instead:

```
compile('com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0') { force = true }
```

This is what finally solved the bug.