# Get Derived ("Blessed") Version of Dependency from Spring Boot Gradle Plugin

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project which uses "blessed" dependencies via the Gradle plugin. The `dependencies` block in my `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

  compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core"
  compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv"
}
```

(I've removed several other dependencies for brevity.)

The above code is broken because Spring Boot does not have a "blessed" version for the `dataformat-csv` extension.

All I want to do is get it to use the Spring Boot-derived version for `jackson-core` and use it for the `jackson-dataformat-csv` as well for consistency. How do I get the version number for that dependency if it's been derived by a plugin?

Comment: You you should be able to see the derived dependencies.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-out-a-dependency-tree

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using? 1.3 uses a separate dependency management plugin that gives you access to the managed versions. See the section in the [README](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/blob/master/README.md) on accessing properties from imported boms.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - That looks pretty slick! Looking forward to it when 1.3 is out of RC!

Comment: @jny - I know I can list them, but I want to be able to update the version of Spring Boot and have all the supported dependencies update appropriately. After looking at Spring Boot 1.3, though, it looks like my setup will change significantly anyway.

Comment: @Andy, it seems it can be done. You can asses the dependencies parse them and set appropriate version, however, if 1.3 will contain changes that solve this problem, I'm not sure if it's worth doing.

Comment: @Opal - Thanks for the insight. You're probably right about it not being worth messing with right now.