# Gradle dependency tree, what does the (*) mean?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

I am just wondering what does the (*) mean under the dependency tree for Gradle. I have been searching online and could not find any answers.

```
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6 -> 4.5 (*)

    |    +--- org.apache.jena:apache-jena-libs:2.12.1
    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-tdb:1.1.1
    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-arq:2.12.1
    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-core:2.12.1
    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.10
    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.jena:jena-iri:1.1.1
    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6 -> 1.7.10
    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
    |    |    |    |    |    +--- xerces:xercesImpl:2.11.0
    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01
    |    |    |    |    |    \--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
    |    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6 -> 4.5 (*)
    |    |    |    |    +--- com.github.jsonld-java:jsonld-java:0.5.0
    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.3 -> 2.5.1
    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.3 -> 2.5.1 (*)
    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.7 -> 1.7.10 (*)
```

Answer (score 41):

`(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)`

Should be displayed under your dependency tree.

The dependencies of the marked dependency are omitted for readability because they were already listed higher up in the dependency graph output.

Also,

`(c) - dependency constraint`
`(n) - Not resolved`

Comment: What this "->" meaning Example  org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6 -> 4.5

Comment: That's a version substitution, based on whatever resolution strategy is in effect.

Comment: @RaGe, doesn't 4.2.6 -> 4.5 (*) mean that the version used is 4.5, the latter?

Comment: @joeybaruch Yes

Comment: what does (c) mean in gradle tree graph ?

Comment: @isJulian00 `(c) - dependency constraint`

Comment: What does "(n)" mean? Is there a official Gradle documentation for this?

Comment: (n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies with the same coordinates that can occur multiple times in the graph are omitted and indicated by an asterisk(*). Dependencies that had to undergo conflict resolution render the requested and selected version separated by a right arrow character(->).

gradle manual: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html