# How do I view all the dependencies of a library?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I know how to view all the dependencies in my Android Studio project but it doesn't show which libraries require which ones. They are just all grouped together. Is there a way to see which libraries are required by each specific dependencies I declare in my build.gradle file ?

Comment: Run the `dependencies` Gradle task to get a tree representation.

Comment: ok thanks alot bro it worked, btw do you know the difference between running dependencies and androidDependencies ?

Comment: I'm not sure what `androidDependencies` is for, and it does not seem to give us a tree. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: do you know if a dependency will still show in the tree if it was needed by another library and shown in that librarys tree ? When I only declare 1 library in my build.gradle file it shows a few different librarys in its dependency tree, but when I declare multiple different librarys in my build.gradle file, it only shows 1 library underneath the dependency tree for the library that previously showed alot more when I declared only that library in the build.gradle ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question. Provide your sample Gradle configurations and the dependency report for each, and perhaps we can help answer your questions.

Comment: thanks but I figured it out here :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231139/gradle-dependency-tree-what-does-the-mean

Comment: @CommonsWare are you familiar with AndroidX replacing support library ?

Comment: Yes, though that's a complex subject. If you are not finding answers (here or elsewhere), I recommend a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can explain your concerns.

Comment: do you know how I would solve the problem of different librarys requiring different google support librarys they have "strictly (c)" next to them.  Im stuck on this

Comment: Talk to the developers of those libraries, I guess. If the libraries are open source, you could try forking them and upgrading their dependencies. Again, you might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you show a specific scenario and ask for advice.

Comment: The libraries are actually open source but since I’m kind of new to doing this do you know how I could go in and change the dependencies ? I’ve never had to do it before is it possible in Android Studio ?

Comment: You could start by getting a copy of the project, import it into Android Studio, and see if you can build it, perhaps using a demo app in that project, Then, you can look at the library's `build.gradle` and see if you can tweak its dependencies to meet your needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose you want to get dependencies graph of your app module. In your terminal/command line, run the below command:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

Moreover, if you want to store the dependency graph generated by above command, just do:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies > dependencies.txt
```

Please note that the dependencies.txt file will be generated and stored in your current working directory.

Comment: do you know why there is so many different dependency trees ? which ones are the main ones I should be looking at ? And do you know how I would solve the problem of different librarys requiring different google support librarys they have "strictly (c)" next to them.

Comment: Ideally, I would recommend you to have a look at `debugCompileClasspath`. But all of these, combined may create conflicts when working on larger projects. So this is something I follow, if I strictly need to remove/modify a dependency, I exclude/modify it from debug first, which is normally your app or flavour build.gradle. Then you can also write specific rules for each of the type, e.g. testing, release, debug and so on.

Comment: If you have to remove a specific dependency, regardless of it's a strict or not, google dependency or third party, you can use something like:

    ```implementation("your.main.dependency:version", {
        exclude group: "group.name.here", module: "module.name.here"
    })```

e.g.
    ```implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1", {
        exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-v4"
    })```

Comment: is it bad though if we exclude it because doesn't the library include them for a reason, doesn't the library need them so why exclude them ? also when I run ./gradlew app:dependencies it cuts off some of the tree at the top like if the terminal ran out of space or something ? how could I view the whole thing from where I wrote  "./gradlew app:dependencies" all the way to the end ?