# gradle dependency what does (c) and (n) mean?

Tags: gradle, gradlew, gradle-dependencies

extremely close to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231139/gradle-dependency-tree-what-does-the-mean), and asked in comments, but left unclear there.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/k9mail/k-9.git
$ cd k-9/mail/protocols/smtp
$ ../../../gradlew dependencies | grep "4.7.1 (\*)\|4.7.1 (c)\|4.7.1 (n)" | sort -u
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1 (*)
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1 (n)
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:{strictly 4.7.1} -> 4.7.1 (c)
```

What do `(c)` and `(n)` suffixes mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

// Edit Aug 2023: The meaning actually is documented - [Output Annotations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#output_annotations)

Sadly, the Gradle docs do not cover this topic so it is a bit confusing.

Issuing `gradlew dependencies | tail` shows a *legend* explaining the meaning of the printed suffixes.

```
(c) - dependency constraint
(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
(n) - Not resolved (configuration is not meant to be resolved)
```

- [Constraints](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:direct-vs-transitive-deps) are not pulled in unless some other dependency pulls them in.
- Transitive dependencies are listed only once and then omitted.
- Declared just for holding/listing the dependency [not resolving it to a graph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html). This is the case for configurations like *implementation* or *api*.