# Android - able to use AppCompatActivity without support library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

In my application's `build.gradle`, the dependencies are:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Without `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'`, I can still use `AppCompatActivity` and `ActionBar` that are from support v7 library. Any answers explaining the reasons behind will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

It has a dependency with `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`

It means that your project has the appcompat library also if you haven't added it in the `build.gradle`, so you can use `AppCompatActivity` and `ActionBar`

Here the pom file:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>design</artifactId>
  <version>22.2.1</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>22.2.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Also you can display the dependency tree with the command `gradle dependencies`.
You can read more [info here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies). (src: [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-out-a-dependency-tree))

Comment: Gabriele Mariotti: thanks, https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Updated design support libraries like**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: That's true for sdk 23, but right now mine is still targeting at sdk 22 so will keep it until move on to 23.