# Firebase send push notification twice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I wrote a very simple android app to test firebase push notification and I get one notification twice.

this is the manifest service:

```
<service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

this is the app gradle:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and here is the project level gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Could you give us a portion code wheren messaging is handled ?. The error could be from that part.

Comment: @isnotmenow this is all of code that related to firebase except google-services.json

Comment: there is should be a receiving class service in your android code, something like MyFirebaseMessagingService.java.

Comment: @isnotmenow You can see that I use basic class instead of My*.java

Comment: I'm sorrry. It's turn out that you use FirebaseMessagingService.java. Take a look at that class.

Comment: You need to be sure that the device is not being registered more than once. I once had that mistake, deleting duplicates solved the problem for me.

Comment: @Omolara I think you are right an I registered twice but how to avoid this?

Comment: @SiavashA You can store a boolean or a value that makes you know when the device is successfully registered. Then you check this value before initiating a new registration.

Comment: @SiavashAbdoli I'm also getting a similar kind of multiple notification but after a period of time. Not 2 notifications at a time. Any idea?

Comment: @SachinPrasad I don't know maybe server send it again after one fail and it cause duplication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0` (which includes play-services-gcm) and `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0`

FCM from firebase-massaging automatically registers an Instance ID token (device ID) so if you have logic that registers for a token in your app it is likely that you are registering twice. This could account for you receiving multiple notifications. More generally though you should not use FCM and GCM in the same app for exactly this reason. So if you are going to use FCM you should remove GCM from your app.

Also, using play-services includes all the play-services-x APIs like play-services-gcm and play-services-drive etc. So always use the split libraries like play-services-x instead of just play-services.

Comment: If the device is registered twice in a production app . Please suggest solution for it?

Comment: You also need to make sure you clean your build to remove all GCM related classes This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785262/receiving-the-fcm-notifications-multiple-times-on-nougat/49177709#49177709

Answer (score 5):

For me it was a 3th party sdk that was using GCM while our app was using FCM. Registering with both services will give you two notifications.

(Also I was calling `super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)` in my FirebaseMessagingService causing a third notification to appear :p

Comment: seems one 3th party sdk use GCM and i don't know wichone :D how to find that?

Comment: Use logic. Most libraries don't need GCM. Big (payed) services with admin panels or with build in chat. Things like Parse, Intercom, payment services etc. could use it.

Comment: Also: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: For me it was AndroidJobs which is using GCM to schedule Notification to older devices.

Comment: Thanks for that (Also...) - that was exactly why I was seeing two :-)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Below is what worked:

I used `data-messages` instead of `display-messages` so that even if the app is in foreground or background, the only single notification will appear.

Replace

```
{
      "to": "/topics/journal",
      "notification": {
        "title" : "title",
        "text": "data!",
        "icon": "ic_notification"
       }
}
```

With

```
{
  "to": "/topics/dev_journal",
   "data": {
       "text":"text",
       "title":"",
       "line1":"Journal",
       "line2":"刊物"
   }
}
```

Reference : [How to handle notification when app in background in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase?rq=1)

Comment: YES! The second example fires the onbackgroundmessage function.. more here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem when application was in background or closed (and sending both notification and data). Caused by requesting old GCM permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44435980/1533285

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" 
android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
  <intent-filter> <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
  <category android:name="${applicationId}" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

from AndroidManifest.xml

This worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use in build gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

and use `handleIntent()` in receiver.