# Sending notifications using Firebase FCM and Google App Engine

Tags: android, node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed [this tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) to send notifications between android devices.  I used Google Cloud App Engine for the first time to run the Node process, and it works. I get notifications, but I get **two** notifications for each request instead of one for each. Can someone help me finding out why?

Some observations...

1. On the App Engine dashboard, I noticed that there are two instances. I tried deleting one, but it won't get deleted. [image: google cloud app engine dashboard]
2. I confirmed that the problem is not in the firebase database. When creating notificationRequest, only one node is created as expected. But two notifications are sent out to the device, probably by the node script.
3. Here is my Node script. I deployed this script by executing `gcloud app deploy` on terminal.

> ```
> // [START app]
> 'use strict';
>
> const express = require('express');
> const app = express();
>
> var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
> var request = require('request');
>
> // Your Firebase Cloud Messaging Server API key
> var API_KEY = [my_api_key]; 
>
> // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
> var serviceAccount = require(__dirname+"/serviceAccountKey.json");
>
> // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
> firebase.initializeApp({
>   credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
>   databaseURL: [my_databaseURL]
> });
> var ref = firebase.database().ref();
>
> function listenForNotificationRequests() {
>   var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
>   requests.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
>     var request = requestSnapshot.val();
>     sendNotificationToUser(
>       request.to_uid,
>       request.from_username,
>       request.message,
>       function() {
>         console.log("Successfully sent");
>         requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
>       }
>     );
>
>   }, function(error) {
>     console.error(error);
>   });
> };
>
> function sendNotificationToUser(to_uid, from_username, message, onSuccess) {
>   console.log("sending message `"+message+"`...");
>   request({
>     url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
>     method: 'POST',
>     headers: {
>       'Content-Type' :' application/json',
>       'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
>     },
>     body: JSON.stringify({
>       notification: {
>         title: from_username,
>         body: message
>       },
>       to : '/topics/user_'+to_uid
>     })
>   }, function(error, response, body) {
>     if (error) { console.error(error); }
>     else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
>       console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
>     }
>     else {
>       onSuccess();
>     }
>   });
> }
>
> // start listening
> listenForNotificationRequests();
>
> // Start the server
> const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
> app.listen(PORT, () => {
>   console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
>   console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
> });
> // [END app]
> ```

4. This is how it is logged for two requests. [image: log example]

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase send push notification twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38167125/firebase-send-push-notification-twice)

Comment: I agree that this does seem like a duplicate of the quesiton @Adam linked.  Regarding question #1, the default when deploying applications to the flexible environment (such as Node) is a [minimum of 2 instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#automatic_scaling).  Unless specified otherwise, the platform will to spawn new instances until that minimum is met.  As for pushing duplicate notifications, I'd defer to [the question Adam linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38186335/5317173).

Comment: Thank you @Adam and Nicolas. Those links helped!