# NoClassDefFoundError - However, class loaded according to verbose:class

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

While debugging our product, I already found a NoClassDefFoundError which is however weird to me- I noticed following output from the class loading log(by turning on -verbose:class):

```
[Loaded com.xxx.yyy.preferences.PreferencesMgr from file:/C:/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/zzz.jar
```

**PreferencesMgr** is just the class that causes NoClassDefFoundError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.xxx.yyy.preferences.PreferencesMgr
```

So it seems that jvm actually has already loaded the class sucessfully. Then why there is a NoClassDefFoundError? What possibilities?

Comment: Maybe some dependencies is missing. Show full log.

Comment: The log is too huge to be posted here. While I go through the log but find no other exceptions.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` here could indicate a different class required during initialization of PreferencesMgr. Check initialization sequence of it for some info.

Comment: @qingjinlyc then post whole exception. I think it may contain inner exception (You can see it after "caused by").

Comment: Also I should mention that if you use custom ClassLoaders it may result in class loaded in one of them and searched in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are clear now. 
**PreferenceMgr** depends on another jar which has bug in certain version. In gradle, we set the bug version of the jar. Thus when loading PreferenceMgr, classloader trigers the bug in MAUtils and results in **NoClassDefFoundError**.

Comment: did you bump the version of PreferenceMgr or add a working MAUtils?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a dependency issue, another package might also define a PreferenceMgr Class which causes conflicts. With Gradle, you can use some commands to check the dependencies: [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree#35235229)