# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'. - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have an App written with react-native and it's worked wonderfully previously **but** when I install [RN async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage). I don't change anything in the native Android code

I got an error when running the app.

I'm trying to remove it and rebuild my app BUT the issue is still I don't know why!

I'd tried to run these command

```
rm -rf node_modules 
npm install
```

then

```
cd android && gradlew clean
```

and it's building successfully without any error

but after running `react-native run-android`

I got

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
> merging dex archives:    The number of method references in a .dex
> file cannot exceed 64K.   Learn how to resolve this issue at
> https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

So how can I solve it?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

So here is the solution.

First, let us solve the multiDex issue.In your `myapp/android/app/build.gradle` file, look for the block of code inside android and defaultConfig and then add the line `multiDexEnabled true` as shown below:

```
android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        ...
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true //ADD THIS LINE 'multiDexEnabled true' Inside the defaultConfig code block
    }

}
```

Second, an effective way to clear npm is by first deleting node_modules folder and then running the command `npm i` and then `npm start --reset-cache`

Third, an effective way to make a gradlew clean is by running this command `cd android` and then `gradlew clean .`

After running these steps, you should be good to go.
All the best.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to uninstall a npm package is

`npm uninstall <name> --save`

If you simply remove `node_modules` it wont be removed from `package.json` file, when u do npm install again the package will be installed if is not removed from `package.json` files [moe detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066532/how-to-uninstall-npm-modules-in-node-js)
In the last line in the error log its mentioned as

**The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K. Learn how to resolve this issue at**  to fix this error u [might need to enable multidex as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36786721/5706413)

Comment: after build the app crashed with bug could not find class android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

Comment: @OliverD go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47031968/getting-error-building-app-apptransformdexarchivewithdexmergerfordebug

Answer (score 0):

It might be the minSdkVersion issue. Try minSdkVersion = 21 at dir. android/build.gradle.

Follow this answer-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61341015/10638877