# Find lib dependencies with gradle 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

[image]

There are many libs in my android project *External Libararies* and I want to know where they come from.

I used the command line: *gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency*  mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235229/5148946)

Try to find the *recyclerview* lib as you can see in the picture above

> gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency recyclerview

But find nothing:

```
Task :app:dependencyInsight
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':app:compile'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

witch reminded me that there is no *app:compile* configuration in my *build.gradle* file. After gradle 3.0 *compile* has been replaced by *implementation* and *api*. So I changed the command line as below:

> gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration implementation --dependency recyclerview

but went wrong:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:dependencyInsight'.

Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I googled a lot about this bug but cannot find a answer. 
Later I replaced all the '*implementation*' with '*compile*' in *build.gradle* file, and used the first compile-configuration command line, and it worked.

```
E:\AndroidApps\SqliteLearn>gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency recyclerview

Configure project :app
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
... ...

Task :app:dependencyInsight
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0
\--- com.android.support:design:26.1.0
     \--- compile

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

It appears that the command line above only works with compile configuration.
Is there a command line that can do the same job and works with implementation configuration？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph, there you find the various new configurations and which are resolvable and consumable.

I think what you want is `runtimeElements` or `runtimeClasspath`, not sure which one will work in that situation.

You can also use the `dependencies` task instead without giving a configuration, that will resolve and display all configurations with their dependencies.