# How to use newer version of a library with Spring Boot

Tags: selenium, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, maven-bom

I am developing an application using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE, and I am using Gradle as build tool.

I want to use SelenumHQ 3.8.1 in the project.

When I was building the project I noticed that Selenium 2.53.1 was added to project (not 3.8.1), so I investigated and found out the reason.

There exists following statement in my build.gradle:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.9.RELEASE")
    }
}
```

and in that file selenium.version property is set to '2.53.1'.

So I have changed the statement to

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.5.9.RELEASE") {
            bomProperty 'selenium.version', '3.8.1'
        }
    }
}
```

but now IDEA shows both 3.8.1 and 2.53.1 as dependencies of the project, and when I build the artifact using gradle, there only exists 2.53.1 dependencies and no sign of 3.8.1.

How can I change this behavior and use Selenium 3.8.1?

P.S. The Selenium is made of multiple jar files, so it is not just a single Jar file, and I want to update all of them in the most minimized using gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer in [here](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/Brussels-SR4/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html#getting-started-overriding-versions-gradle).

I shall override the property using: `ext['selenium.version']='3.8.1'` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When IntelliJ imports the dependencies, it will not remove old dependencies like this.

You would have to clean it out, then re-import the dependencies. Of course, another dependency might also have a dependency on 2.53.1 that would bring it in again.

I don't know Gradle, but maven you can do a mvn tree dependency that would list all the dependencies and further down and you can look through it to see if selenium is a dependency for another dependency too.

Comment: I have removed and readded the dependency multiple times, but the problem still exist in Idea.

Comment: I recommend getting the dependency tree to print out and search for selenium in the results. In maven it is 

    mvn dependency:tree

I recommend using the link I posted below to get the gradle version of dependency tree to see if anywhere else you have a transitive dependency on Selenium with a different version.

Comment: Here is a link in StackOverflow for getting the tree in Gradle. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree