# Spring Boot / Security classloader issues with Keycloak run from terminal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, classloader, keycloak

I use Spring Boot and Spring Security in combination with Keycloak. The build tool is gradle.

When I run `./gradlew bootRun` the application works flawless. If I use the resulting fat jar (i.e. `java -jar myapp.jar`) the application will boot but I encounter an exception when the application tries to invoke some keyloak stuff:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.ensureVisible(Proxy.java:851) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.validateProxyInterfaces(Proxy.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:203) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:999) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.proxy(ProxyBuilder.java:79) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.build(ProxyBuilder.java:131) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.proxy(ClientWebTarget.java:93) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realms(Keycloak.java:114) ~[keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realm(Keycloak.java:118) ~[keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
```

So I figured out that there must be something wrong how I start the application in the terminal. I found [this official site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html), which explains how to run an Spring application from terminal. So I tried all of the solutions including:

```
$ unzip -q myapp.jar
$ java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

but I get the same error.

After 2 days of searching and experimenting I'm out of any ideas.

So my question is basically:
**Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?**

My knowledge regarding the classloader is also limited - so any pratical hints in this direction are very welcomed as well.

**EDIT (added build.gradle):**
There were some Jackson problems that's why the Spring web dependencies are included directly (without the starter and therefor without Jackson).
Here is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
   ext {
      kotlinVersion = '1.2.20'
      springBootVersion = '1.5.7.RELEASE'
      keycloakVersion = '3.4.3.Final'
      restEasyClientVersion = '3.1.4.Final'
      postgresServerVersion = '10.0'
      postgresJdbcDriverVersion = '42.1.4'
      spekVersion = '1.1.5'
      jacksonVersion = '2.8.10'
      javaxWsRsVersion = '2.1'

      logbackVersion = '1.2.3'
      slf4jVersion = '1.7.25'
   }
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
      //spring dev
      maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
      maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
      //Kotlin dev
      maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.2' }
      //gradle plugins
      maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
   }
   dependencies {
      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
      classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
      classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
      classpath('com.bmuschko:gradle-docker-plugin:3.2.0')

      //for tests
      classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
   }
}

allprojects {

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      jcenter()
      //spring dev
      maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
      maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
   }

}

subprojects {

   repositories {
      maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.2' }
      // for tests
      maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/spek" }
   }

   // for kotlin
   apply plugin: 'kotlin'
   // for tests
   apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

   apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
   apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
   apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

   // for tests
   junitPlatform {
      filters {
         engines {
            include 'spek'
         }
      }
   }

   sourceCompatibility = 1.9

   dependencies {
      // kotlin
      compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVersion}")
      compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:${kotlinVersion}")
      compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:${kotlinVersion}")
      // jackson
      compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jacksonVersion}"
      compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jacksonVersion}"
      compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:${jacksonVersion}"
      compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:${jacksonVersion}"
      compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.2"

      // Java WS RS
      compile "javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:${javaxWsRsVersion}"
      // for tests
      testCompile "org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:${spekVersion}"
      testRuntime "org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:${spekVersion}"
      testCompile ("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-api:${spekVersion}") {
         exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
      }
      testRuntime ("org.jetbrains.spek:spek-junit-platform-engine:${spekVersion}") {
         exclude group: 'org.junit.platform'
         exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin'
      }
      // spring security
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
      testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
      // begin: spring web without jackson
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
      compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
      compile('org.springframework:spring-web')
      compile('org.springframework:spring-webmvc')
      testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
      // end: spring web without jackson
      // Keycloak
      compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-security-adapter:${keycloakVersion}")
      compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-adapter:${keycloakVersion}")
      compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-tomcat8-adapter:${keycloakVersion}")
      compile("org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:${keycloakVersion}")
      compile("org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:${restEasyClientVersion}")
      compile("org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:${restEasyClientVersion}")

   }

   compileKotlin {
      kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
      kotlinOptions.allWarningsAsErrors = true
   }
   compileTestKotlin {
      kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }
}
```

Comment: I would bet you've got some conflict between two different resteasy versions. You could use `gradle dependencies` to list all the dependency tree and see what you've got there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I took a look but all the dependencies regarding resteasy seem to be equal (i.e. 3.1.4.Final). So I checked the keycloak dependencies as well but they are equal, too.

Comment: could you post your gradle configuration?

Comment: I added build.gradle. It's a multiproject setup, so to reduce complexity I removed a lot of stuff (the original file is >400 lines) - of course, all the dependencies are included!

Comment: You should include either the spring boot adapter + tomcat adapter or the spring security one, but not both together. See [the docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.html).

Comment: Ok, I tried all combinations with spring boot adapter / tomcat and spring security. Also, [as stated in the docs](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.3/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-security-adapter.html#springbootingeration) under **Spring Boot Integration**, I tried using *Keycloak Spring Boot Starter* as a dependency instead of the others mentioned above. Still, no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the underlying class loader of `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` which is used by `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`.

Because the problem and the solution is complex [please refer to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113207/completablefuture-forkjoinpool-set-class-loader/49426561#49426561) for better understanding.

This question is only kept alive for this cross reference (and may hopefully lead others to the correct solution).