# CompletableFuture / ForkJoinPool Set Class Loader

Tags: java, spring, classloader, completable-future

I tackled down a very specific problem, whose solution seems to be something basic:

My (Spring) application's classloader hierarchy is something like this: `SystemClassLoader -> PlatformClassLoader -> AppClassLoader`

If I use Java `CompleteableFuture` to run threads. the `ContextClassLoader` of the threads is:  `SystemClassLoader -> PlatformClassLoader -> ThreadClassLoader`

Thus, I cannot access any class in `AppClassLoader` although I have to because all external library classes reside there.

The source base is quite large so I don't want to/can't rewrite all the thread related pieces to something else (e.g. pass a custom executor to each call).

So my question is: **How can I make the threads created by e.g. `CompleteableFuture.supplyAsync()` use the `AppClassLoader` as a parent?** (instead of the `PlatformClassloader`)

I found out that [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) is used to create the threads. But as it seems to me, everything there is *static* and *final*. So I doubt that even setting a custom [ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.html) with a system property will help in this case. Or would it?

**Edit to answer the questions from the comments:**

- *where do you deploy to? Is this running within jetty / tomcat / any JEE container?*

  - I'm using the default Spring Boot setup so an internal tomcat container is used.
- *What is the exact issue you have?*

  - The exact issue is: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader**
- *The jobs that you submit to supplyAsync() are created from the AppClassLoader, aren't they?*

  - The `supplyAsync` is called from the `MainThread` which uses the `AppClassLoader`. But, debugging the applications shows that all such threads have `PlatformClassLoader` as their parent. As to my understanding, this happens because [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) is constructed during the application startup (because it's static) and so uses the default class loader as the parent which is `PlatformClassLoader`. So, all threads from this pool get `PlatformClassLoader` as their parent for [ContextClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader--) (instead of `AppClassLoader`).
  - When I'm creating my own executor inside the `MainThread` and pass this executor to `supplyAsync` everything works - and I can see during debugging that indeed now `AppClassLoader` is the parent of my `ThreadClassLoader`. Which seems to affirm my assumption in the first case that the common pool is not created by `MainThread` at least not when it's using `AppClassLoader` itself.

**Full stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.keycloak.admin.client.resource.RealmsResource referenced from a method is not visible from class loader
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.ensureVisible(Proxy.java:851) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.validateProxyInterfaces(Proxy.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyBuilder.<init>(Proxy.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.lambda$getProxyConstructor$1(Proxy.java:426) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:203) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyConstructor(Proxy.java:424) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:999) ~[na:na]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.proxy(ProxyBuilder.java:79) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.build(ProxyBuilder.java:131) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.proxy(ClientWebTarget.java:93) ~[resteasy-client-3.1.4.Final.jar!/:3.1.4.Final]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realms(Keycloak.java:114) ~[keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.realm(Keycloak.java:118) ~[keycloak-admin-client-3.4.3.Final.jar!/:3.4.3.Final]
```

Comment: where do you deploy to? Is this running within jetty / tomcat / any JEE container?

Comment: What is the exact issue you have? The jobs that you submit to `supplyAsync()` are created from the `AppClassLoader`, aren't they? So they should have access to its classes. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments! Please find the answers in the edited question above. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide the full stacktrace of your exception. Also, this might be something specific to `keycloak` – so the corresponding tag might be relevant.

Comment: I added the full stacktrace up to the point where I called the failing method.

Comment: So that's exactly the same issue as you had in [Spring Boot / Security classloader issues with Keycloak run from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385997/spring-boot-security-classloader-issues-with-keycloak-run-from-terminal). Did you solve that in the end? I also notice that this error message is specific to Java 9. Did you try in 8? It could be a regression.

Comment: Unfortunately, Java 8 is not an option. But thanks for the suggestions! And yes, this is the same issue. I will cross link the two questions. I found a solution for this one and will post it soon (though I'm not proud of the solution as it is really dirty).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, here is a very dirty solution of which I'm not proud of and **may break things for you** if you go along with it:

The problem was that the classloader of the application was not used for `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. Because the setup of commonPool is static and therefor during the application start up there is no easy possibility (at least to my knowledge) to make changes later. So we need to rely on **Java reflection API**.

1. create a hook after your application successfully started

   - in my case (Spring Boot environment) this will be the [ApplicationReadyEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationReadyEvent.html)
   - to listen to this event you need a component like the following

     ```
     @Component
     class ForkJoinCommonPoolFix : ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
         override fun onApplicationEvent(event: ApplicationReadyEvent?) {
       }
     }
     ```
2. Inside your hook you need to set `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` of commonPool to a custom implementation (so this custom implementation will use the app classloader)

   - in Kotlin

     ```
     val javaClass = ForkJoinPool.commonPool()::class.java
     val field = javaClass.getDeclaredField("factory")
     field.isAccessible = true
     val modifiers = field::class.java.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
     modifiers.isAccessible = true
     modifiers.setInt(field, field.modifiers and Modifier.FINAL.inv())
     field.set(ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory())
     field.isAccessible = false
     ```
3. Simple implementation of `CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`

   - in Kotlin

     ```
     //Custom class
     class CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory : ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {
       override fun newThread(pool: ForkJoinPool?): ForkJoinWorkerThread {
         return CustomForkJoinWorkerThread(pool)
       }
     }
     // helper class (probably only needed in kotlin)
     class CustomForkJoinWorkerThread(pool: ForkJoinPool?) : ForkJoinWorkerThread(pool)
     ```

If you need **more information about reflection** and why it's not good to change final fields [please refer to here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516381/changing-private-final-fields-via-reflection) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection). Short summary: due to optimizations the updated final field may not be visible to other objects and other unknown side effects may occur.

**As stated before: this is a very dirty solution. Unwanted side effects may occur if you use this solution. Using reflections like this is not a good idea. If you can use a solution without reflection (and post it as an answer here!).**

**Edit: Alternative for single calls**

Like stated in the question itself: if you only have this problem in a small number of places (i.e. it's no problem to fix the call itself) you can use your own [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). A simple example [copied from here](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2015/11/which-thread-executes.html?m=1):

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final CompletableFuture<String> future = 
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { /* ... */ }, pool);
```

Comment: Added a working solution without reflection. This should work for you as well given you are already hooking up a CustomForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory that has the correct class loader.

Answer (score 17):

One possible solution valid in jdk11 (tested using Spring Boot 2.2) is to take advantage of the new constructors in `ForkJoinPool`

The main idea is to create a custom `ForkJoinPool` using a custom ThreadFactory that uses our own ClassLoader (not the system one -this behavior starts in jdk9-)

**A bit of history**
Before jdk9 `ForkJoinPool.common()` returns an Executor with a ClassLoader of your main Thread, in [Java 9 this behave changes](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8172726), and return an executor with the system jdk system classloader. 
So it's easy to find ClassNotFoundExceptions inside CompletableFutures code while upgrading from Java 8 to Java 9 / 10 / 11, due to this change.

**Solution** 
Create our own factory like [Neo said in an anwser before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57551188/878015) and use this factory yo create a ForkJoinPool and an Executor

```java
MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = new MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory();

ForkJoinPool myCommonPool = new ForkJoinPool(Math.min(32767, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()), factory, null, false);
```

Use it like this

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
   log.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().toString());  
   // will print the classloader from the Main Thread, not the jdk system one :)
}, myCommonPool).join();
```

**Extraball**
If your are behind a Spring based app, should be necesary to add your Spring Security Context to the new custom thread pool

```java
@Bean(name = "customExecutor")
public Executor customExecutor() {
    MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = new MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory();
    ForkJoinPool myCommonPool = new ForkJoinPool(Math.min(32767, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()), factory, null, false);

    DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor delegatingExecutorCustom = new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor(myCommonPool, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    return delegatingExecutorCustom;
}
```

And use it autowiring like any other resource

```java
@Autowired private Executor customExecutor;

CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    ....
}, customExecutor).join();
```

Answer (score 16):

I ran into something similar and came up with a solution that does not use reflection and seems to work well with JDK9-JDK11.

Here is what the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) say:

> The parameters used to construct the common pool may be controlled by setting the following system properties:
>
> - java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory - the class name of a ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory. The system class loader is used to load this class.

So if you rollout your own version of the `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` and set that instead to use the correct `ClassLoader` using the system property, this should work.

Here is my custom `ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory`:

```
package foo;

public class MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory implements ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory {

    @Override
    public final ForkJoinWorkerThread newThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
        return new MyForkJoinWorkerThread(pool);
    }

    private static class MyForkJoinWorkerThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread {

        private MyForkJoinWorkerThread(final ForkJoinPool pool) {
            super(pool);
            // set the correct classloader here
            setContextClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        }
    }
}
```

and then set the system property in your app startup script

> -Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory=foo.MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory

The above solution works assuming that when the ForkJoinPool class is referenced the first time and it initializes the `commonPool`, the context ClassLoader for this Thread is the correct one that you need (and is not the System class loader).

Here is some [background](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8172726) that might help:

> **Fork/Join common pool threads return the system class loader as their thread context class loader**.
>
> In Java SE 9, threads that are part of the fork/join common pool will always return the system class loader as their thread context class loader. In previous releases, the thread context class loader may have been inherited from whatever thread causes the creation of the fork/join common pool thread, e.g. by submitting a task. An application cannot reliably depend on when, or how, threads are created by the fork/join common pool, and as such cannot reliably depend on a custom defined class loader to be set as the thread context class loader.

As a result of the above backward incompatibility change, things that uses the `ForkJoinPool` that used to worked in JDK8 may not work in JDK9+ .

Comment: This solution is not working in JDK9+, as you said, so I will post a new complete solution based on your solution below. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the classloader in MyForkJoinWorkerThread constructor be set like this?
`setContextClassLoader(MyForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.class.getClassLoader());`

Answer (score 8):

It seems that resteasy lib uses thread context classloader to load some resources:
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-client/3.0-beta-1/org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/ProxyBuilder.java#21.

When resteasy try to load the requested class, it will ask the thread classloader to look for it and load it if possible, when the requested class is located in a classpath not visible by the classloader, the operation fails.

And that exactly what happens to your application:
**ThreadClassLoader** tried to load a resource located in the application classpath, since resources from this classpath are accessible only from **AppClassLoader** and its children, then the **ThreadClassLoader** has failed to load it (**ThreadClassLoader** is not a child of **AppClassLoader**).

A possible solution could be to override the thread context ClassLoader by your app ClassLoader:
`thread.setContextClassLoader(appClass.class.getClassLoader())`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is basically what I already know but nevertheless I'm thankful for any constructive comment :) I upvoted your answer so you get some reputation for being able to post comments ;)

Comment: thanks for the up-vote :)
yep, I wanted to post it as a comment, but since I cannot I was obliged to put it as an answer.