# Is there any difference between parallelStream() and ExecutorService?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a list of heavy tasks that should be run in parallel. I like the java Stream API and don't want to touch `Executors` directly, for that reason I've written the following code:

```java
Set<Runnable> tasks = Set.of(heavyTask(),…);
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Quite often (not always!) my concurrency tests fails during “heavy task” execution. OK, probably it's a race condition. I've rewritten the code using `Executors` directly:

```java
try {
    Set<Callable<Object>> tasks = Set.of(heavyTask(),…);
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
        .invokeAll(tasks).forEach(future->{
            try {
                future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ignore) {
        }
    });
} catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
}
```

The problem with heavy tasks is gone. I'm really confused.  I thought that `parallelStream()` uses `Executors` under the hood and it's almost the same. Is there any difference between `.parallelStream()` and `ExecutorService`? Or maybe `forEach` isn't correct termination operation in the first code example?

Comment: We might have more insight if you were more specific about the nature of your concurrency tests and the failures observed in them.

Comment: `invokeAll(tasks)` does already invoke all callables and return when all of them have been completed. There is no point in chaining a `forEach` with an action that does nothing but call `get` without using the result. Besides that, try to use `List.of(…)` instead of `Set.of(…)`. That might give you better parallel processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parallelStream` uses the [fork/join common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) which is an Executor, so you're right, it's almost the same.

The fork/join pool is used for all kinds of things so maybe some other, unrelated task was interfering. By declaring the Executor yourself, you are guaranteeing 4 dedicated threads.

`forEach` is a fine terminal operation for the first example. The one to avoid would be `forEachOrdered`, which breaks the parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

### `ExecutorService` vs `parallelStream()`

From the first sight they are interchangeable approaches since `parallelStream()` uses `ForkJoinPool` that uses `Executors` in turn. The syntax sugar if you want.
But it isn’t always the true.  The `ForkJoinPool` (and therefore `parallelStream()`) since Java 9 returns `Executor` with the `ClassLoader` that differ from the main `ClassLoader` from which you probably forked.
It could lead to strange problems: I had the library that wasn’t loaded by the `ClassLoader` from `ForkJoinPool` and I got `ClassNotFoundException`, one of the possible solutions is:

```java
final ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(task -> {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
    task.get();
});
```

But as for me - it doesn’t look so well and by that reason, for my particular case, I decided to use pure `Executors` without any side effects. You can find more solutions of the problem in that [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113207/completablefuture-forkjoinpool-set-class-loader/57551188#57551188). I hope this helps someone.

Comment: What exactly is `task`? In your question, you had a stream of `Runnable`  instances, which do not have a `get()` method. Besides that, depending on the thread’s context loader is a self-made problem. Java doesn’t use that loader, so it’s some code explicitly using `currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead of using the intended loader in the first place…

Comment: @Holger thank you for your valuable reply. Do you mean that instead of `currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` it's better to use some kind of a particular class loader? And I don't clearly understand why using of thread’s context loader is a self-made problem. Do you have any sources where I can read more about it?

Comment: Ordinary code dependencies are [resolved by using the defining class loader of the class containing the reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.1). The same applies to `Class.forName(String)`, without a class loader argument; it will use the caller’s defining class loader. The only way to have the code using the thread’s context loader, is by explicitly querying and using it, which is mostly a convention among 3rd party libraries. If you do not want a dependency to the thread executing the code, do not use the thread’s context loader.