# Using async and sync method in one spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have one spring bean which contains two methods. One method is asynchronous with @Async annotation and second is not. Both methods are accessing SOAP endpoint client, generated with jaxws-maven-plugin. Method not annotated with @Async works fine. But method annotated with @Async sometimes fails with exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl". But this exception is really sporadic, not thrown always.
Example of code:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  @Transactional
  public void createTask(URL url) {
    new TaskService(url).getTaskServicePort().createTask();
  }


  @Async
  @Transactional
  public void getTask(URL url) {
    new TaskService(url).getTaskServicePort().getTask();
  }
}
```

Is it problem of asynchronous method call?
Why I sometimes get this ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl ?

I would expect both methods works without throwing exception.

**Update:** I forgot to mention.

Java version is 17, Spring Boot version 2.7.4

Comment: ClassNotFoundException does not sound right for this case, can you please https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Answer (score 1):

So it seams that I solved it. Even I do not understand completely the problem.
I found some hints here [CompletableFuture / ForkJoinPool Set Class Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49113207/completablefuture-forkjoinpool-set-class-loader/59444016#59444016)

I made changes in my spring configuration according this post.
Here are my changes:

```
  @Bean(name = DAMAGE_CALCULATION_THREAD_POOL_TASK_EXECUTOR)
  public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
     ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory forkJoinWorkerThreadFactory = ForkJoinThread::new;
     ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool =
     new ForkJoinPool(Math.min(32767, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()), forkJoinWorkerThreadFactory, null, false);
     return new DelegatingSecurityContextExecutor(forkJoinPool, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
  }
  private static class ForkJoinThread extends ForkJoinWorkerThread {

    protected ForkJoinThread(ForkJoinPool pool) {
      super(pool);
      this.setContextClassLoader(
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    }
  }
```

Currently it is already more than two weeks and this error do not appear. So I think the problem was in classloader. But do not know what exactly was the problem.