# Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl

Tags: android, gradle, android-multidex

As the title says, Multiple dex files are being defined, I'ven been digging around with no luck on how to solve this one, so I decided to reach out on the community, to make the story short, I'm updating the gradle build system of this legacy project from gradle 0+ to gradle 3+, I managed to refactor the common configurations such as flavoring, dependencies (from compile to api/implementation), (you name it..), until I stumbled on this dex issue, the first thing that came to my mind is to break down the dependencies by the help of [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree), but unfortunately its taking my time too much on gradlew commands and still ending up with gradlew issues(unable to execute AndroidSdk something), so I took a step back(to minimize the time I needed) and did this... (playing the odds)

```
dependencies {

api (project(':<omitted project name>')) {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

api (project(':<omitted project name>')) {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

implementation ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.5.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation (group: 'commons-io',name:'commons-io',version: '2.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation (group: 'com.jcraft', name: 'jsch', version: '0.1.44-1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.android.support:design:23.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation (group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation (group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-vfs2', version: '2.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
api files('libs/nfc7003.jar')
api files('libs/minilcd7003.jar')
api files('libs/Scan7003.jar')
api files('libs/UserInterface.jar')
api files('libs/printer7003.jar')
}
```

I cant figure out whos dependency in the above list has this transitive issue with the logging framework, I define an exclusion on them all, still no luck..

just to mention the reason behind : I need the advance profiling of Android studio 3, and the latest gradle(4+)/build tool(3+) must be used to be able to do so, that lead me here ..

please help me on this one, thanks in advance...

[Edit] Build message:

```
 Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
 Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
 Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$2;
 Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
 Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$2;
 Error: at 
 com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
 Error: at 
 com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
 Error: at 
 com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
 Error: at 
 com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
 Error: at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
 Error: at 
 com.android.builder.dexing.
 DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
 Error: at 
 com.android.builder.dexing.
 DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
 Error: at java.util.concurrent.
 ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
 Error: at 
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 Error: at 
 java.util.concurrent.
 ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
 Error: at 
 java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
 Error: at 
 java.util.concurrent.
 ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
 Error:Execution failed for task '
 :<omitted project name>:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
 com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define 
 Lorg/apache/commons/logging/impl/LogFactoryImpl$2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are using duplicated library in your build.gradle.

**First**, for support library, you need to use the same version. Do not use the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

implementation ('com.android.support:design:23.1.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}
```

instead use the following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'

// appcompat is implicitly include within support design.
```

**Second**, for google play service, use the same version. Do not use the following:

```
implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}

implementation ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'logging'
}
```

instead use:

```
// Dont use the whole play service library
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
```

**Third**, to exclude common-logging you need to use something like this:

```
compile(group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-compress', version: '1.3'){
    exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

or use the following:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
}
```

You don't need to adding exclude to every library because some library didn't have any commons-logging inside them.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, just 1 question before I apply the changes, where should I put the configurations method? is it inside the android { .. } ? or outside of it?

Comment: Thanks so much, it solved the multi dex issue, just have to deal with the conflicts and clean some stuffs(its gonna be nightmare now), thanks anyway :)

Comment: Glad it helps you. I hope you sleep well ;)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
```

remove all exclude options and commons-io.
above dependency might just work fine

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried it hours ago(without all the exclusions yet, removed the commons.io dependency), still no luck, but let me try it again after all the changes and attempts I made, lets see if there will be any progress..