# Gradle error when adding the support library

Tags: android

I'm trying to make my app use [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html)

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

}

What I newly added in:

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.4.0'
```

The error is about the first dependency:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

It says:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 25.4.0, 25.3.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.4.0 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion.)

Comment: You could try [listing your dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree) to figure out where the different support library versions are referenced from, which could help you figure out how to fix your configuration.

Comment: the latest is 27.1.0. Also you can check which dependency lib uses a different version with   gradlew.bat app:dependencies or ./gradlew app:dependencies depending on OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's telling you exactly, all

```
com.android.support:**
```

Should use the same version

Change it to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
```

Comment: Did you try clean project? invalidate caches/restart?

Comment: Sounded weird so i ran it for my self with the same exact dependencies i wrote above. everything works fine (except it fails to resolve photoview, but that's irrelevant so i removed it).

Important to note that if you're using lib version 25 you need to use compileSdk 25, and same for 24 if 24...

Answer (score -1):

Always use/update same support library version so replace your code with:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:design:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:preference-v7:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:preference-v14:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.4.0'){force true}
compile ('com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0'){force true}
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
compile 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
compile 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.3'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

To get duplicate dependency report check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41784667/8399299)