# Android. Find out what is causing dependency version clash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

[image]

I have this non-critical yet very annoying error in my gradle. 
Problem is that I can't figure out which of my libraries is causing this version clash. Is there a way to find it out?

Comment: Run a Gradle dependency report: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235229/115145