# Duplicate zip entry [okhttp-3.10.0.jar:okhttp3/HttpUrl$Builder$ParseResult.class]

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, proguard, okhttp

Here I am transfering third party library volley to retrofit.Actually I had used retrofit in many projects,But this is some unique problem and solution not getting from google also.

Here app **Build Gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xyz"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 31
    versionName "7"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled="true"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.googlecode.java-diff-utils:diffutils:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Here Project **Build Gradle**:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    google()
 }
}
```

Here is a retrofit ApiClient Code:

```
public class ApiClient implements AppConstants{

public static final String BASE_URL = APP_URL1;
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build();
    if (retrofit == null) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Here is an error:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\A\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\debug\0.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Abhi.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\3.10.0\7ef0f1d95bf4c0b3ba30bbae25e0e562b05cf75e\okhttp-3.10.0.jar(;;;;;;.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [okhttp-3.10.0.jar:okhttp3/HttpUrl$Builder$ParseResult.class]))

Comment: Did you added **multiDexEnabled=true** ?

Comment: yeah I had added  multiDexEnabled=true

Comment: actually I had modified and just showed here few gradle dependencies.

Comment: Maybe try to delete the gradle cache at `C:\Users\Abhi.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1` gradle will download all needed jars the next time you build your project again. This way you can rule out any issues with your locally stored copies of the needed dependencies.

Comment: @dpr :I tried to delete files-2.1 still same issue.

Comment: just see I had updated my Question and do give me solution.

Comment: @AbhishekBardolia please add the output of `gradlew dependencies` to your question. The problem is probably that there are two different versions of okhttp on the classpath.

Comment: @dpr See gradlew dependencies added in question.

Comment: @AbhishekBardolia my fault for android the command is slightly different. It's `gradlew app:dependencies` where `app` is your project module. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: @dpr Can you please elaborate seen your link...I guess I am new in this can you pl elaborate??

Comment: See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree) perhaps? The output I requested is not from `gradlew dependencies` but from `gradlew <app>:dependencies` where `<app>` is the name of your application project.

Comment: Thank you sir@dpr for this solution it is best so far.I got it

Comment: This was actually not thought to solve your problem. Please add the output of `gradlew <app>:dependencies` to the question.

Comment: yeah you are right....but by your way i got a solution i was having two okhttp and other was in one library,I had deleted and now the problem is solve.

Comment: Maybe you could post your solution as answer to your own question. This way others will be able to see that this question was solved and may benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate others for solution but special thanks to @dpr
Here is a solution regarding my problem.We can see all dependencies in

**Select View** > **Tool Windows** > **Gradle** (or click Gradle  in the tool windows bar).

Expand **AppName** > **Tasks** > **android and double-click androidDependencies**. After Gradle executes the task, the Run window should open to display

We can get all dependencies:

```
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0@aar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0@jar
+--- com.android.support:transition:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0@aar
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0@jar
+--- android.arch.persistence:db-framework:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.persistence:db:1.0.0@aar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0@aar
+--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0@aar
+--- android.arch.core:common:1.1.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.0@jar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1@jar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0@jar
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0@aar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0@jar
```

Apart from gradle it will show you in folder which is duplicate so we can find and delete and can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I already putted this code at gradle file still not working same error duplicate zip