# all com.android.support libraris must use the same version

Tags: android, android-support-library

https://snag.gy/9kujyf.jpg

Here's a screenshot...

This line has the error

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

This line are the 2 libraries I added per the popup recommendation.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

How can I correct this? I've tried so many of the methods here already but none work for me, so I posted my specific situation. Thanks!

Here's my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.cast.thought.thoughtcastandroid"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' 
    wearApp project(':wear')
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    implementation project(':iskn_api-release')
}
```

*EDIT* Added the gradle file

Comment: can you please add the code of your gradle file. It would be really helpful.

Comment: yes sir done thank you

Comment: Never use a plus in a version number

Answer (score 3):

I have tried the gradle code of yours, what I found was that when you are using some other libraries like in this code of yours mentioned below.

```
   wearApp project(':wear')
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
    implementation project(':iskn_api-release')
```

Now what happens is when these libraries were formed mostly there SDK version was maybe 26 or 27, so when we add such libraries it shows a conflict of dependencies because we are not using the same SDK version, therefore, there is no perfect solution that I could find out but for this particular case two more dependencies that I added removed the error. The code is shown below.

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Kindly add the 2 dependencies in your gradle file if still, the problem arises kindle check the classpath version in project gradle, mine was 3.1.3 same is shown below.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Hope that solves the issue.

Comment: This code saved my life seems like the only solution to a very weird problem

Answer (score 0):

The error says you have 2 versions of the support library included - 26.1.0 as well as 28.0.0-alpha3. This means one of your other libraries has a dependency on version 26.1.0.

Check the dependency tree graph from the terminal using this command:
- `gradle app:dependencies` or `./gradlew app:dependencies`
- `app` is your project module

Find out which library has the same dependency of version 26.1.0 and exclude it in gradle. For example:

```
dependencies {
     implementation('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0') {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'appcompat-v7'
     }
 }
```

Comment: you do not have enough ram. change ram options from gradle.properties

Comment: what is this? Please post the issue

Comment: You said that I should run this to see dependencies, so I ran it, and it made no sense to me, these are the result of my 'gradle dependencies'

Comment: i dont see any dependencies here. you should see something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44725823/4260786

Answer (score 0):

I had a problema with the build.gradle(Module: app) for Android Studio 3.1 (compile SDK versión 28) and i've done this modification

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lovaton.kinley.conteointerfaz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding those conflicted dependencies with newer versions in app level gradle solved the issue.

for eg.

```
def SUPPORT_VERSION = "28.0.0"

implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"

// added below dependencies to resolve conflict 
// these dependencies have different version for some different sdk i am using
implementation "com.android.support:support-media-compat:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${SUPPORT_VERSION}"
```