# how to locate a specific dependency in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I use `owasp dependency-check:dependencyCheckAnalyze` to verify dependency vulnerabilities.

It always shows that `apple:AppleJavaExtensions` has a severe vulnerability, but I don't remember I use this dependency.

I tried to locate this dependency using `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency AppleJavaExtensions` but it says `No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':compileClasspath'`.

How to find this dependency to fix the warning?

**update:**
runtime dependencies graph: https://pastebin.com/uDpiiSUM

Comment: Can you share your gradle dependency file?

Comment: Doesn't this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree?

Comment: it shows a very long list that my console could not display all of them. So I used `./gradlew buildEnvironment --scan`, but it does not contain any apple dependency.

Comment: Are you building with the version of Java that comes with Mac OS X? If so, you should try to get hold of a recent JDK and use that. 1.8.x at the very least. I suspect that's where the vulnerability is coming from, not your Gradle dependencies.

Comment: @PeterLedbrook no, I build in Linux.

Comment: Well, a Google search on AppleJavaExtensions definitely seems to indicate that it's specific to Java on Mac OS X. I have absolutely no idea why you'd see it on Linux. Is the build doing anything unusual? Alternatively, is there a `buildscript {}` block or any extra configurations that the build defines?