# Can I determine which library class belong?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have for example class `LivePagedListProvider` that that is in the `android.arch.paging` package.

Is there any direct way to determine which library in gradle file this class belongs to?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: That link for running `gradlew :app:dependencies` is not fine grained enough as it does not show the individual classes. A very useful tool nonetheless.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like this class is `deprecated` and hidden, so it not meant to be used by us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in Android Studio, by using the *Navigate... Class* menu option (or pressing *CTRL-N* on Windows).

Press *CTRL-N*, and when the search box opens up, start typing the name of the class you want to find.

[image: CTRL N search for class]

As the matches are shown in the list below, to the right of each match will be shown which gradle dependency this class belongs to.

---

If you choose to open the class, then in the top left of your screen you will also see the name of the library.

[image: showing library that class is in]

This is useful because it lets you navigate around that JAR file, by clicking the various parts of the package name, but does not give you the full gradle dependency which is shown in the search box above.

Comment: @sandeor30r I use this `CTRL-N` all the time for navigating around my projects. you might also enjoy `CTRL-SHIFT-N` which allows you to open non-class files e.g. XML layout files or `strings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

A faster way I prefer is to use **Search Everywhere** box. Double tap shift key and in dialog that opens you can type your class name and its gradle dependency will be shown next to class name in suggestion drop-down.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure you can say its *the* easy way, but it works for me.

For Mac, `cmd`+ Click (`control` + `Left Click` for Windows ) on that Class(not object) will take you to the declaration, where the Class actually exists.From that Class' package name, you can confidently tell which gradle project `implementation` that belong to, as both of them will be same.