# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail, liferay-7

The line `part.writeTo(out);`
throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`:

> com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler

```
private static void getBodyAsRFC822(
        MimePart part, boolean ignoreHeaders, ByteArrayOutputStreamout) {
    try {
        out.reset();

        if (ignoreHeaders) {
            OutputStream os = MimeUtility.encode(out, part.getEncoding());
            part.getDataHandler().writeTo(os);
            os.close();
        } else {
            part.writeTo(out);
            out.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(e);
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle

```
compileOnly group: 'com.liferay', name: 'com.liferay.portal.instance.lifecycle', version: '2.0.0'
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.46.0"
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"

compileInclude group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
compileInclude group: 'org.apache.mina', name: 'mina-core', version: '2.0.16'
compileInclude group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'
compileInclude group: "javax.servlet", name: "servlet-api", version: "2.5"
```

But `multipart_mixed implements DataContentHandler`, so it should be castable. Why isn't it?

Comment: it seems to be a classloading issue. Check the libs you have in your portlet or hook or any other component

Comment: where ? In my buld.gradle?

Comment: Let's talk into chat. It's not correct for all other developers if we talk into italian

Comment: I'll contact you tomorrow, thanks

Comment: OK in the meantime give a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: Hi Angelo, i'm new about StackOverflow. How can i open a chat with you ?

Comment: i can't lunch a chat because i have only 1 reputations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a subclass apparently can't be typecasted to its legitimate superclass, you have duplicate classes, loaded by different classloaders. Find where you load the activation (superclass) classes, eliminate all but one (typically you'll need to eliminate the one class that your own project brings) and use the provided one from the framework.

The Exception message names the classes in question but omits the classloaders participating in the game, which is why the message, on first attempt to understand it, doesn't make much sense. As soon as you know about multiple classloaders, thus multiple instances of `javax.activation.DataContentHandler`, it makes more sense.

Edit: With the `compileInclude` statements in your build.gradle, you're effectively bundling all your dependencies into your own jar file. But the framework has its own version of these classes, and while they all have the same name, they'll now be different versions (not only numeric), loaded through different classloaders. You should only use `compileInclude` if you clearly are dependent on something that you'll never find in the OSGi runtime. Instead, use `compileOnly` or `compile` as default, and deploy the additional dependencies to the runtime, together with your module.

Check [this article](https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/osgi-module-dependencies) for a detailed description of what you've done.

Comment: Where i can find the activation (superclass)?

Comment: I don't know, but you should be able to find it twice

Comment: Basically, what can I do?

Comment: if you can, look my build.gradle.. i can to change "compileInclude group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4'" with "compileInclude group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.6'" and the exception disappears but 
the application does not do that before ..

Comment: `compileInclude` will package the dependencies *in your module*, and most likely `javax.mail` (and with it `javax.activation`) is already provided by the OSGi container (Liferay in this case). Thus `compileOnly` should be ok: At compiletime you'll need the dependency, and at runtime you're dependent on the version of `javax.mail` that Liferay or another component provides through the OSGi container. As a rule of thumb, it should be rare that you're bundling dependencies within your own module. `compileInclude` will include `javax.mail` and `activation` in your module.

Comment: if i change compileInclude with compileOnly, the exception there is

Comment: At least you have the root cause for this problem. Now find the others ;)