# javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.Message

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, liferay-7, mime-message, message-listener

`javax.mail.Message mimeMessage = (javax.mail.Message)array[1];` throws

```
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.Message.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to javax.mail.Message
```

```
public void Receive(Message message) throws Exception {

    Object[] array = (Object[])message.getPayload();

    FileVersion sourceFileVersion = (FileVersion)array[0];
    javax.mail.Message mimeMessage = (javax.mail.Message)array[1];
```

Comment: This suggests a classpath problem with multiple JavaMail libraries being used.

Comment: so what can i do? i mus change compileInclude with compileOnly ?

Comment: Find out where the classpath issue is coming from and fix it. Prime candidates are things like JavaMail being included in your application and in your application server.

Comment: ok i understand, thanks !

Comment: Duplicate of [java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart\_mixed cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55403413/java-lang-classcastexception-com-sun-mail-handlers-multipart-mixed-cannot-be-ca). The root cause is *exactly* the same as in the question  that you asked a couple of days ago.

Answer (score -2):

That's because you are casting MimeMessage to Message, try changing as below,

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage = (javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage) array[1];
```

Comment: A [`javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) extends `javax.mail.Message`, so the cast is appropriate. The fact it doesn't work indicates a classpath problem.

Comment: If this worked the original code would work too. The error message already states explicity that this doesn't work.. Answer is pointless.