# Duplicate class in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar and dagger-2.22.jar

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

After upgrading all libraries to androidx and to the latest versions of Firebase libraries

I got error with 2 different versions of dagger java files, link in the error message doesn't work. Problem occurs at step `:app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses`.

I do not use dagger directly in my code, using

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

I found what `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.1.0` uses `com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22`, but no info about `1.2.2`.

```
Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class dagger.Lazy found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (dagger-1.2.2.jar) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.MembersInjector found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (dagger-1.2.2.jar) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.Module found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (dagger-1.2.2.jar) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class dagger.Provides found in modules dagger-1.2.2.jar (dagger-1.2.2.jar) and dagger-2.22.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Inject found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Named found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Provider found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Qualifier found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Scope found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)
Duplicate class javax.inject.Singleton found in modules javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject-1.jar) and javax.inject-1.jar (javax.inject:javax.inject:1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Comment: as a workaround I solved problem by using 17.0.0. version

Comment: Will you please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629996/5108695 and provide the `dependency` Graph. Or just post the `Dependency` details so that we can investigate, which dependency is actually creating problem

Comment: I can solve this, I did these kinds of jobs a lot in my project, Just need your Dependency tree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to analyze dependencies.

## SOLUTION #1 (console only)

Run in console:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies
```

[image]

After receiving list of dependencies in the console, go to `Analyze` part (below `Solution #2`).

---

## SOLUTION #2 (generate html)

## 1) Add plugin to generate report

In to `app/build.gradle` (this with `compileSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion` or `buildTypes`), at the top add:

```
apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

near one of them:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

which are on top.

## 2) Generate report

Just from the console run:

```
 ./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

or from Android Studio

```
Tasks > other > htmlDependencyReport
```

[image]

## 3) Open report

In console you will find URL:

```
./gradlew htmlDependencyReport


> Task :app:htmlDependencyReport
See the report at: file:///Users/user_name/your_path/project_name/app/build/reports/project/dependencies/index.html
```

And go to the `project ':app'`

[image]

## 4) Analyze report

After clicking each of the position there are dependencies:
[image]

To expand all of them, you can in develper console such code:

```
$('#dependencies').html(function(index, html) {
    return html.split('style="display: none;"')
               .join('style="display: block;"')
               .split('<h3 class="closed">')
               .join('<h3>')
});
```

---

## ANALYZE

## 1) Find old dependencies

In your case you are searching phrase `dagger:1`

[image]

Or in the console:

[image]

## 2) Exlude dependencies

Find in the report library name, and just `exclude group` from this import.

In your `build.gradle` (where you have all of dependencies) modify "problematic" library excluding dagger v1.

For example:

```
implementation("some.old.library.using.dagger1:1.0.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.dagger', module: 'dagger'
}
```