# Updated firebase dependency and got duplicated protobuf classes error

Tags: android, firebase, protocol-buffers

I'm getting this error after updating one of my firebase SDKs

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
...
```

My app now depends on `protobuf-lite` and `protobuf-javalite`, which triggers the duplicate class error.

Answer (score 14):

Recently, Firebase Android has migrated from depending on the old `protobuf-lite` to depend on `protobuf-javalite` ([github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1152) | [PR implementing the change](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/pull/1534)).

You need to update **all the firebase SDKs affected by this change together**, otherwise the old SDKs will pull the wrong dependency into your app.

Here is the list of affected SDKs and their versions supporting `protobuf-javalite`

```
- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:19.1.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-abt:19.1.0
- com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8
```

EDIT: Added `firebase-perf` to the list, as it transitively depends on config and also needs to be updated.

Comment: I am currently using `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0`. As far as I know, this is the latest version, but I still get the error.

Comment: Do you also depend in any other of the SDKs in the list? You need to update all of them.

Comment: No. Only `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0`. I ended up downgrading to previous version.

Comment: Most likely other non-firebase dependencies in your app are pulling the `protobuf-lite` dependency. Check here on how to get the dependency tree for your app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was `androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-alpha02` library that depends on `protobuf-lite` which conflicts with `protobuf-java-lite` being used by Firebase. Updating this library helped.

You can check if other libraries depend on conflicting `protobuf-lite` by calling `./gradlew app:dependencies` in Terminal. Then cmd+f and search for `proto`.

Comment: You're right, latest crypto libraries don't depend on protobuf anymore https://dl.google.com/android/maven2/androidx/security/security-crypto/1.0.0-rc03/security-crypto-1.0.0-rc03.pom

Answer (score 2):

This burned me because [`com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:17.1.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-cast-framework/17.1.0) through at least [`com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:19.0.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-cast-framework/19.0.0) transitively depends on [`com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-lite/3.0.1) through its dependency on [`com.google.android.datatransport:transport-backend-cct:2.0.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.datatransport/transport-backend-cct/2.0.1) through [`com.google.android.datatransport:transport-backend-cct:2.1.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.datatransport/transport-backend-cct/2.1.0).

Someone from Spotify filed an issue about this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161831470

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by manually searching in the Gradle dependency tree and updating the problematic SDK afterward.

For Android, use this line

```
gradle app:dependencies > dependency_tree.txt
```

or if you have a gradle wrapper:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependency_tree.txt
```

where `app` is your project module.

Then manually search for `proto` for problematic SDK within the `dependency_tree.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that you are importing two packages that use Protobuf for your project, one of them has a distribution that's conflicting with the other.

If you encountered this problem on Flutter, you can reconsider the version number of your dependencies in pubspec.yaml, and replace "any" by an exact version number. 
For example, under "dependencies:" change:

```
barcode_scan: any
```

To:

```
barcode_scan: ^2.0.0
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

try to degrade

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
```

It works with

```
implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:18.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I just downgraded my `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.5.0` -> `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution just add the boom library for firebase and remove library version for libraries it will resolve the library conflicts

```
 // Import the Firebase BoM
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')

 // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies

  // Declare the dependency for the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```