# Duplicate class in protobuf lite and protobuf java and protobuf javalite

Tags: android, flutter, dart

This issue happen , after added those packages firebase_auth: ^1.3.0, cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0
, firebase_core: ^1.2.0  with this package   barcode_scan: ^3.0.1

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DoubleArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExperimentalApi found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$EntryAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$IteratorAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$SetAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyEntry found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteArrayListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteStringListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$Metadata found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteToString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Parser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1) Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtobufArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.14.0 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)

Comment: Need more information. Can you share your build.gradle ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764605/updated-firebase-dependency-and-got-duplicated-protobuf-classes-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updated firebase dependency and got duplicated protobuf classes error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62764605/updated-firebase-dependency-and-got-duplicated-protobuf-classes-error)

Comment: no , it doesn't work for me