# Spring boot application: how to trace exact starter which dependency particular jar came from?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I've a legacy Spring boot application with many dependencies ( standard spring's like web and custom users as well) each dependency artifact has it's own dependencies list and so on. At the top of all of this I see something like:

```
import org.apache.commons.bla.bla.*
```

I wanna trace which particular dependency it came from? I see the

```
apache.commons.
```

jar in the project classpath tree ( I use IDEA) but it only shows the jar is here, but not where it came from.

Are there any ways to trace the chain of the dependencies or at least a bottom dependency where it came from?

Comment: `gradle dependencies`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gradle dependencies
```

is the more or less acceptable answer. Just expose the whole dependency tree and then use search to find a possible dependency which might have similar name to jar file and then see the chain of dependency.
If there are more straightforward way I'll appreciate it and remark as the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> how to trace exact starter which dependency particular jar came from?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+mouse-click on the package you'd wish to trace. This will get you to the corresponding dependency, in the dependency tree.

Comment: 1) "This will get you to the corresponding dependency" - yes, but I need the path of tree dependencies. 2) "View -> Tool Windows -> Maven -> and then expand Dependencies" - this way prune manually search and expand all tree. 3) actually gradle dependencies  - is what I need, but thank you for your effort!

Comment: *but I need the path of tree dependencies.* - what do you mean exactly? 2nd point is correct, I wrongly provided you a maven example, which I removed (although, I'm sure there should be an alternative window for gradle).