# How to get the Dependencies(direct & transitive) for android modules built using soong (Android.bp)

Tags: android-source, android-soong

In aosp module containing Android.bp file uses soong m to build them

In gradle project we can get the dependecies using

> gradle dependencies

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235229/2018343

Is there similar command in soong? or is there anyother way to do get the dependencies?