# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension' / Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

what could be wrong:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
> Could not resolve androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta07

As I haven't added compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta07, so I don't have any idea what could be the problem.

Gradle snippet

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    implementation "io.github.aakira:napier:1.5.0"
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    //for bottom sheets
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Mentioned dependency may appear in your project transitively from another dependency. To check full dependency tree run `./gradlew app:dependency` or [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/) from command line. Then you can check the tree and find out which dependency needs compose 1.0.0-beta07.

Comment: Also check compose version in composeOptions section in build.gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` set it your app `build.gradle.kts`:

```
android {
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.1"
    }
}
```