# Hazelcast dependency hazelcast-spring:4.2.2 adds hazelcast-spring:3.11.6

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, hazelcast

When I add `hazelcast-spring:4.2.2` it adds version `3.11.6` into WAR file. Why is that?

```
compile ("com.hazelcast:hazelcast-spring:4.2.2")
```

Comment: This could be because of transitive dependency  , can you generate dependency tree and check

Comment: Take a look at this question to see how to do this with Gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree