# Weird behavior after upgrading to androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0

Tags: android, google-maps, preference

I am using Google Map in my Android app, was working properly, now after upgrading

androidx.preference:preference-ktx from **1.1.0** to **1.2.0**,

Google Maps stopped displaying map tiles, but everything else is working, tap on map works, ...

Comment: location callbacks stopped working on my end using 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Hi did you check the dependencies `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0` brought? It is possible that some transitive dependency of `androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0` may have caused the update to the same transitive dependency of the Google map library. See [Gradle dependency resolution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_resolution.html) for more info

Also you can print the dependencies tree using the command `./gradlew app:dependencies` where `app` is the name of the application Gradle project. See [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree) post for the same

To fix  the issue you have to manually resolve the dependency using below Gradle code

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'culprit dependency group' && details.requested.name == 'culprit dependency version') {
            details.useVersion 'fixing version'
            details.because 'reason why we have fixed the version'
        }
    }
}
```

Details bout dependency resolution at [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/resolution_rules.html)

Answer (score 0):

In 1.2.0, it added ktx dependencies. It is already posted in Google's issue tracker, but seems Google would not fix it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/238425626

You can have two ways to resolve the issue.

1. Force using 1.1.1

build.gradle > dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
```

2. Remove ktx dependencies from 1.2.0

build.gradle > dependencies

```
implementation('androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel'
    exclude group: 'androidx.lifecycle', module:'lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx'
}
```