# Need to resolve startup errors after removing database dependencies from SpringBoot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-initializr

I recently created a new SpringBoot (version 3.0.6) project (via Initializr) and initially included some database-related dependencies. Now that I've gotten all of the fundamental functionality implemented, I realized that I don't actually need the app to directly interact with databases directly, so I wish to remove those dependencies.

I removed the obvious dependencies from my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jpa'
runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
```

Remaining dependencies include:

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-file'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-security'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
```

I also removed the database connection info from `application.properties`:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/MyApp

instance.lock=false

#debug=false
spring.devtools.restart.log-condition-evaluation-delta=false

logging.level.org.me=debug
logging.level.org.springframework=info
logging.level.root=warn

server.ssl.enabled=false
server.port=8111
server.ssl.key-store=src/main/resources/server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=JohnDoe
server.ssl.key-password=blahblah

# TEST:
spring.rabbitmq.host=rmq-server
spring.rabbitmq.port=5671
spring.rabbitmq.username=messageUser
spring.rabbitmq.password=abc123

spring.rabbitmq.virtualhost=/vhost
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.my.request.queue=me.q.app.request
spring.rabbitmq.my.response.queue=me.q.app.response
```

Now when I start the app I'm seeing:

```
2023-05-18T14:16:32.376-05:00  WARN 29920 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-05-18T14:16:32.429-05:00  INFO 29920 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-05-18T14:16:32.453-05:00 ERROR 29920 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Apparently something is still telling Spring that there should be a database, but I can't find where. Any suggestions on what else I need to remove in order to completely remove database-related dependencies would be appreciated.

I've tried doing various attempts at running `gradle clean build --refresh-dependencies`, and rebuilding the project (in IntelliJ). I also started a new SpringBoot project with similar initial configuration to my app, but without the database dependencies, so that I could compare with my project, but was unable to find relevant differences.

When I run `gradle dependencies`, nothing with "jdbc", "jpa", or "sql" was returned.

Comment: Did you remove the database entry from the configuration itself?

Comment: Check your dependency tree with [gradle dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21645071/5873923). It looks like you're still depending on JDBC.

Comment: Yes, I previously deleted the database configuration/connection info from application.properties.

Comment: I ran "gradle dependencies" and nothing with "jdbc", "jpa", or "sql" was returned.

Comment: can you post your application.properties

Comment: application.properties has been added.