# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenMap

Tags: scala, apache-beam, jackson-databind

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:804)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:722)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1395)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:1131)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline.<clinit>(TestPipeline.java:253)

. . .

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenMap
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.ScalaTypeModifier.<init>(ScalaTypeModifier.scala:15)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.ScalaTypeModifierModule.$init$(ScalaTypeModifier.scala:54)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.<init>(DefaultScalaModule.scala:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:780)
    ... 61 more
```

Nowhere in our code do we directly call `GenMap` but it seems to be a side effect of calling `jackson` in our tests.

The error happens at

```
public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();
```

specifically `org.apache.beam.sdk.testing.TestPipeline` in

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class BeamUtilsTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeamUtilsTest.class);

    @Rule
    public final transient TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

    @Test
    public void testJoins() throws Exception {
        Map<String, PCollection<JsonNode>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("users", pipeline.apply("readUsers",
                                    BeamUtils.readJSONFile(pathOfResource("join-data/users.jsonl"))));
        map.put("accounts", pipeline.apply("readAccounts",
                                       BeamUtils.readJSONFile(
                                               pathOfResource("join-data/accounts.jsonl"))));

        JsonNode joinExpression = JsonFile.read(pathOfResource("join-data/usersAccounts.json"));
        PCollection<JsonNode> joinedCollection = BeamUtils.join(map, JsonBuilder.newBuilder().set("/withJoin",joinExpression).build());
        Map<String, String> validationMap = new HashMap<>();
        validationMap.put("mickey.mouse", "AD01");
        validationMap.put("minni.mouse", "AD05");
        validationMap.put("donald.duck", "AD06");
        PAssert.that("Join fields should exist", joinedCollection)
           .satisfies((SerializableFunction<Iterable<JsonNode>, Void>) jsonNodeIterable -> {
               jsonNodeIterable.forEach(jsonNode -> {
                   logger.info(jsonNode.toPrettyString());
                   if (!jsonNode.path("userId").isMissingNode()) {
                       String userId = jsonNode.path("userId").textValue();
                       assert !validationMap.containsKey(userId) || jsonNode.path("accountId").textValue() != null;
                   }
               });
               return (Void) null;
           });
        pipeline.run();
    }
```

## Context

I am trying to upgrade our project from Java 8 and older to Java 11 and 17, where most of my time has been spent in dependency hell, especially dealing with the various base version of Scala, old Apache Spark code, and other things.

This is simply the latest problem I am trying to resolve, but I have been fighting it for so long, I am not clear on backing out of the problem.

The test context is various services running under Docker. While I have some experience with Beam, and using dealing with JSON in Beam, I did not write this test, and I am a little mystified why `jackson` needs Scala libraries.

At this point, I would appreciate some insights as I am getting a little brain-dead working on this issue, and losing my ability to think creatively.

I noticed that `scala.collection.GenMap` was removed in newer versions of Scala, so this may also be a contributing factor. Adding

```
testImplementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.9'    // scala.collection.GenMap
. . .
testFixturesImplementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.9'    // scala.collection.GenMap
```

to our build.gradle file does not seem to help.

Comment: spark has [jackson-module-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala) as dependency. I guess the error is related with that. Not all [scala releases are comptaible with jdk 17](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html). Spark supports jdk 17 since 3.3.0. Without knowing which version of each library are you using is hard to know what is causing the issue. Is it possible to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If you generate the complete dependency tree, there's a good chance you find the conflicts. Otherwise share it with us (mainly where Scala, Spark and Jackson appear).

Comment: @GastónSchabas At this point, I am settling on Java 11 for a target, especially with respect to Scala, Spark, Beam, etc. A minimal reproducible example can be very difficult to engineer, but I will think about it.

Comment: @GaëlJ I have been trying to fathom the dependency tree in IntelliJ, but I cannot seem to get any insights. Perhaps I need to use other tooling to explore the dependency tree...

Comment: you can use [sbt dependencytree plugin](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree) to provide the dependency tree. Based on which sbt version you are using is how the plugin should be installed

Comment: My bad. You are using `gradle`. Not sure how you can print that like in sbt

Comment: just with a quick search, I found [View and Debug Dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html) and the question [Using Gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree). I guess that could help

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to search for dependencies in IntelliJ... sometimes things are not obvious in the GUI. Also, thanks to @GastónSchabas I used Gradle. Neither tool can find GenMap, and that does not surprise me because the error does not show up until Beam is getting invoked with TestPipeline.create(); Based on my Beam experience, troubleshooting can be very frustrating, and this seems to be yet another example.

Comment: there is no way out of dependency hell. All that changes is dependencies move.