# facing the issues while uploading the Bundle to Play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVsXS.png)

I have tried changing the many sdk version but didn't help me out

also I have not used any google ads SDk but still it is showing me this issue.

also tried to enable the ads from play store console but still it is showing the same

Comment: If you have not directly used Ads sdk in your app then probably some other sdk added it as a transitive dependency. Check this to see the dependency tree: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.