# App rejected due to com.flurry.android.analytics library which we not used in app

Tags: kotlin, google-play, google-developers-console, flurry, flurry-analytics

After upload new production version of app on google play console, app got rejected due to violation policy issues for below library, Which we not used in app.

com.flurry.android.analytics

User Data policy: Violation of User Data policy

We reviewed SDKs used by your app and found noncompliant version(s) of SDK(s) which collects persistent device identifiers. Persistent device identifiers may not be linked to other personal and sensitive user data or resettable device identifiers.

We try some result for check which library use this flurry dependecny but no result found.

Please help us to find out solution.

We try this command to check library uses in app.

[Using Gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645071/using-gradle-to-find-dependency-tree)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of your dependencies are using "old" Flurry SDK.
If they are using Flurry version older than 14.0.0, then Google Play Store will reject it. Please see the Flurry Release Note here,
https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/releasenotes/android/#version-14-0-0-10-20-2022

- Report device identifiers and location collection to be Google Policy Compliant.
- Enforce explicit opt-in API for location collection.

You can force your app dependencies to use newer Flurry version by adding the following line in your `build.gradle` `dependencies` section,

```
implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:14.4.0'
```