# Why am I getting over 40 errors by adding three Google-Calendar-API dependencies in Android studio using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, google-calendar-api

I am getting multiple errors in each of the following: (I did not create these)

```
     `IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java
     DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.java
     MergeJavaResourcesDelegate.kt
     IncrementalFileMerger.java
     MergeJavaResWorkAction.kt
     ProfileAwareWorkAction.kt
     StreamMergeAlgorithms.java`
```

I added the dependencies in `build.gradle.kts(Module :app)`.
Dependencies:

```
     `implementation ("com.google.api-client:google-api-client:2.0.0")
      implementation ("com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.34.1")
      implementation ("com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev20220715-2.0.0")`
```

After I saw all of the error I started to edit my build script in my
`build.gradle.kts(Project: projectname)` with this:

```
     `buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
     }`
```

I was hoping that this could have been the issue.
It was this:

```
    `buildscript{
        repositories{
            google()
        }
    }`
```

I was thinking that it could make the difference but I could not even get the classpath to work because it was private and I could not access it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to answer without a full understanding of your project and all its dependencies, and since you don't say what errors occurred in the 7 files you list.

But is seems like you have a **dependency override problem**.  Here's how these problems occur:

Suppose your project already had a dependency called "SomeTools", and this library depends on an old version of GSON.

Now when you include those new dependencies if those include *transitive dependencies* of, say, GSON then the dependency manager needs to decide which version it should use.  If now a different version of GSON is included, this may be incompatible with calls made by, e.g. `IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java` and hence why you have errors.

Using Maven's *dependency:tree* tool to explore the transitive dependencies, you can see that just one of those dependencies you list brings in a lot of other libraries:

```
[INFO] +- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.34.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.42.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.opencensus:opencensus-api:jar:0.31.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.grpc:grpc-context:jar:1.27.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.opencensus:opencensus-contrib-http-util:jar:0.31.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:jar:1.42.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1-android:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.11.0:compile
```

I note that you are using Gradle, so you'd want to use Gradle's equivalent tool. Find information on that in this Question: [Using Gradle to find dependency tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21645071/1847378)

This is how I would go about discovering where the dependency conflict arises.  There are directives you can given Gradle to exclude some dependencies, or to use a particular version.