# Get dependancy libs from Gradle file?

Tags: php, gradle, bintray, jcenter

Let's assume I have the following libraries defined in a gradle.build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2'
    //...
}
```

Now, some of these libraries are dependent on other libraries. **Given the library name, is there a way to know the list of libraries the given library depend on?** I am only interested on the names and versions of those libraries for a webapp project. I tries reading [Bintray API](https://bintray.com/docs/api/) but couldn't find the way to do it there.

---

**EDIT:**

I'm not looking for the dependency tree of my app (i.e. the `gradle dependencies` command). I'm just interested in building a web app, where the user provides any project (hosted in Maven on JCenter) and the web app will return the dependency tree.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Gradle artifact dependency graph command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288133/what-is-the-gradle-artifact-dependency-graph-command)

Comment: Thanks @JBaruch , but I'm not looking for my app's dependencies. I'm interested in showing the dependency tree of a certain project (facebook-android-sdk for example) in a web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the pom file of the library and run `mvn dependency:tree` on it with [`outputType` parameter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputType) set to `graphml`.

Comment: Given the library/project name, how can I retrieve the pom file programmatically? The pom file contains all the info I need, but my problem is how to get it. Maven and JCenter APIs didn't help me.

Comment: that's the same file name with `.pom` as an extension.

Comment: Yes, but how to know the file's url? For example, if I have `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.2` as an input, how to get its [pom file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.8.2/facebook-android-sdk-4.8.2.pom)? The input could be any library the end user provide. Facebook Android SDK is just an example.

Comment: They are in Maven layout: replace `.` with `/` in group id, then the artifactId, then the version, and for the filename it's the artifactId dash the version, and `pom` as extension.

Comment: Fantastic! I tested this with a couple of libraries and it seems consistent. My only concern now is with `https://(repo1).maven.org/(maven2)`. I get the feeling that there is `repo2`, `repo3`, `maven1` and `maven3`.