# Gradle dependecies used but not declared

Tags: maven, gradle

I'm looking for information about Gradle dependencies, similar to this question:

[What is the Gradle artifact dependency graph command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288133/what-is-the-gradle-artifact-dependency-graph-command)

but with a narrower scope.  I'm wondering about functionality that Maven has for analyzing dependencies, and whether or not Gradle includes something similar.  Specifically, Maven can scan your source code and then compare that to your declared dependencies, and determine (roughly) if you have dependencies declared that you aren't using and/or if you're using dependencies that you haven't declared (due to issues related to Turing completeness, this analysis may include false positives/negatives, but I generally find it to be incredibly useful regardless).  Does Gradle have anything similar?  So far I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a thing is not shipped with Gradle at least as far as I know.

You best bet is to search through Google and / or plugins.gradle.org for finding a plugin that does what you want.

I for a short period did this for you and found this one which might be what you want: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.intershop.gradle.dependencyanalysis
I have no idea about its quality or anything, I just searched through plugins.gradle.org, I don't know or ever used that plugin.

Comment: I did search Google and couldn't find anything official.  I found a couple of 3rd party plugins, but I wasn't sure if there was one that was better known that everyone used or... what.  I guess I'll just have to try a couple of them out and see which one works best.