# How do I get IntelliJ to recognize JavaFX as a dependency to a Kotlin project with Gradle?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, kotlin, dependencies

I am finishing a project written by someone else.  The project is written in Kotlin, but I could not get their build system (wemi) to recognize JavaFX, and so I ported it to Gradle instead, since the JavaFX developers have approved instructions for using Gradle (see those [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij)).  Gradle downloads these dependencies normally, and IntelliJ lists them in my external libraries, but I cannot import them into my code.

I am using JVM 11 and Kotlin 1.3.31 with JavaFX 11.0.2.  I have followed these instructions to the letter, and it still does not work.

The error is upon importing classes from JavaFX.  When I attempt to import a class from any JavaFX module, IntelliJ fails to resolve the 'javafx' package. No other errors appear.  By all accounts, if the dependency shows in my dependency list, I should be able to import it, but this is not the case.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using modules? Is this only a problem with IntelliJ or does the code fail to compile when using Gradle as well? Can you show us your build file, please?

Comment: Make sure you have specified these dependencies for the [Gradle source set](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) Use `gradle dependencies` command to see the list of dependencies for each source source https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289367/2000323